# genfromtxt creates 1D array of tuples instead of 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to use scikit-learn to do some classification. However, I'm having trouble just getting off the ground and importing the data.

I am working with this data: [Adult Data Set](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Adult).

I am new to numpy and scikit-learn, so I started following [this tutorial](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/rasbt/pattern_classification/blob/master/machine_learning/scikit-learn/python_data_entry_point.ipynb#Reading-in-a-dataset-from-a-CSV-file), which uses the [Wine dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Wine).

The issues I am having is that the data is imported as a 1D array of tuples instead of a 2D array. There is also missing data, indicated by `?`.

My dataset is not entirely numerical. There are a lot of strings. I read the [genfromtxt doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html), which has examples of how to handle a dataset of mixed type. (Might there be a better way to approach this than what I used below?)

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

all_data = np.genfromtxt(open("./adult.data","r"), dtype=[ 
                      ('age', 'i4'),
                      ('workclass', 'S16'),
                      ('fnlwgt', 'i8'),
                      ('education', 'S12'),
                      ('education_num', 'i4'),
                      ('marital_status', 'S22'),
                      ('occupation', 'S17'),
                      ('relationship', 'S14'),
                      ('race', 'S18'),
                      ('sex', 'S6'),
                      ('capital_gain', 'i8'),
                      ('capital_loss', 'i8'),
                      ('hours_per_week', 'i4'),
                      ('native_country', 'S26'),
                      ('income', 'S5')
                      ],
                      delimiter=",", autostrip=True,
                      missing_values=('?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?'))

# load class labels from column 15
y_adult_labels = all_data['income']

# load the 14 features
X_adult = all_data[:][0:-1]
```

This is creating a 1D array of tuples, where each tuple is a line in the original CSV data file.

Why is this not creating a 2D array? (For starters, something like this `all_data[:,1:]` gives an `IndexError: too many indices for array`.)

I ultimately want to:

- Map the string data to numerical values (somehow... maybe with `converters` in the `genfromtxt` call?
- Process the 2D array (e.g., PCA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A 2D array has to have the same type of content in all cells.  But by your own specification (the dtype) you are loading a mix of numbers and strings.

This is a different kind of 2D array, a structured array.  You index 'rows' by number, and 'columns' by name, e.g. `all_data['income']`.  Those 'tuples' (not really tuples, but they display that way) are the structured array equivalent of a 2D array row.

If you really must access fields by number then index the name from the `dtype.names` list.

Read up on structured (sometimes called record) arrays.

The question of why `genfromtxt` returns a 1d array has been asked many times.

As for the conversion to pure numeric data, I think you will have to work column (field) by column.  Make another array `newdata=np.empty((n,15),dtype=int)`.  Take `all_data['workclass']`, map the strings to numbers, and assign those to `newdata[:,1]=...`, etc.  There is no magic or shortcut.

Comment: Thank you hpaulj for putting me on the correct path.